# Automaically highlighting text in yellow after copy text in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting, highlighting

I'm using Microsoft Word from Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013. With Ctrl + V I can copy highlighted text in Word. Is it possible to automatically highlight text in yellow (or any other color) after I have copied text? So I mark text, then I hit Ctrl + V to copy it and then the marked text should automatically be highlighted in yellow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut of Ctrl + V is Paste, not Copy. The keyboard shortcut of Ctrl + C is for copying. I mention this because your question is not clear. Do you want to highlight the selection in the source document, or highlight the selection after you paste the copied text?

**Assuming you want to copy (Ctrl + C).**

There is not a feature in Microsoft Word that would allow you to copy and highlight with the single copy function. You can however use the Ctrl + C to copy and then immediately press Ctrl + Alt + H and this will highlight the selected text. The highlight color will be the last one you used from Word's Ribbon.

An alternative would be a custom macro that you would invoke with with an assigned keyboard shortcut. The custom macro would be:

```
Sub CopyHighlight()
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
End Sub
```